# running spark with python 2 instead on python 3

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have windows 8.1 pc. Spark and python version information is as below

Is there any way I can set Spark to use python2 instead of 3.5.1?

```
c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6>bin\pyspark
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
16/03/20 20:34:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.1 (default, Jan 29 2016 15:01:46)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
```

I tried below but it failed :(

```
c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6>export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out what is the location of your python2 executable.

For ex. C:\Python2 is directory under which python2.exe is installed/

You need run as following to set the environment variable PYSPARK_PYTHON in windows as follows:-

`set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Python2`

Thanks,
Charles.